Request method 'POST' not supported - Tomcat-server
I have a ValidaAssinaturaDocumentoController controller
package br.ufrn.info.caus.web.acp.controller;

import br.ufrn.info.caus.business.dto.valida_documento.DadosAssinaturaDocumentoDTO;
import br.ufrn.info.caus.business.dto.valida_documento.VerificacaoAssinaturaDocumentoDTO;
import br.ufrn.info.caus.business.model.valida_assinatura_documento.ValidaAssinaturaDocumento;
import br.ufrn.info.caus.web.acp.consumer.ValidadorDocumentoConsumer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * @author Thalisson Muriel (thalisson.muriel@ufrn.br)
 * @since 22/10/2024
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/valida-assinatura-documento")
public class ValidaAssinaturaDocumentoController {

    @Value("${signer.enigma.aes.key}")
    private String keyEnigma;

    @Autowired
    private ValidadorDocumentoConsumer validadorDocumentoConsumer;

    private Logger logger = Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public String validacao(Model model, @Validated @RequestParam(value = "k") String hashAssinatura) {
        model.addAttribute("documentoAssinado", decripter(hashAssinatura));
        return "/validacao_assinatura_documento/validacao";
    }

    private DadosAssinaturaDocumentoDTO decripter(String hashAssinatura) {
        ValidaAssinaturaDocumento validaAssinaturaDocumento =
                ValidaAssinaturaDocumento.builder()
                        .hashAssinatura(hashAssinatura)
                        .keyEnigma(keyEnigma)
                        .build();
        return validaAssinaturaDocumento.getDadosAssinaturaDocumento();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void importar(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("Acessou /upload");

        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Nenhum arquivo foi enviado.");
            return;
        }

        try {
            VerificacaoAssinaturaDocumentoDTO assinaturaDocumento = validadorDocumentoConsumer.validaDocumento(file);
            if (assinaturaDocumento != null && assinaturaDocumento.isValida()) {
                System.out.println("Documento validado com sucesso.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Assinatura inválida ou não validada.");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao importar: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

and I implemented a new Upload method, basically pdf upload, but it keeps giving an error saying that it does not support the post
 method2024-11-14 12:59:26 \[INFO \] http-nio-8080-exec-3 Logger:63 - 2024-11-14T12:59:26.0379Z http://localhost:8080/caus-web-acp/valida-assinatura-documento/upload 0 37    false  

2024-11-14 12:59:26 \[WARN \] http-nio-8080-exec-3 DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver:215 - Request method 'POST' not supported

This is my frontend
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:include="fragments/layout :: page">
<body>
    <th:block th:fragment="content">
        <a class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-sm-4 my-sm-5 my-3" th:href="@{/}" title="Ir para a página inicial">
            <img class="d-none d-sm-block w-75 pb-sm-5" th:src="@{/resources/img/logo-caus.svg}">
            <img class="mw-90 d-block d-sm-none" th:src="@{/resources/img/logo-caus.svg}">
        </a>

        <div class="conteudo-principal">
            <div class="conteudo-principal__header">
                <h1>Valida assinatura de documentos</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="conteudo-principal__content">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Documento:</label>
                    <span th:text="${documentoAssinado.nomeArquivo}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Tamanho (em KB):</label>
                    <span th:text="${documentoAssinado.tamanhoArquivo}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Certificado assinador:</label>
                    <span th:text="${documentoAssinado.certificadoAssinador}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nome do assinante:</label>
                    <span th:text="${documentoAssinado.nomeAssinador}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Data de assinatura:</label>
                    <span th:text="${documentoAssinado.dataAssinatura}"></span>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <form id="formAnexarDocumento" action="/caus-web-acp/valida-assinatura-documento/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input class="custom-file-input" type="file" id="file" name="file" accept="application/pdf">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="file">Escolha seu arquivo</label>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Importar">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </th:block>
</body>
</html>


I've already tried running it in postman and it doesn't work either. I've already tried modifying the return method, but it continues.
